# Enable the zip extension for PHP

Tags: php, zip, extension-methods

I am trying to enable the .zip extension in PHP, but the function below returns false.

```
if (!extension_loaded('zip')) {
    return false;
}
```

How do I enable the .zip extension with out using php.ini?

Is it possible to enable using `ini_set()`?

Comment: is there a ZIP of some description listed when you do a __phpinfo();__

Comment: There are userland implementations of the ZIP extension. Though the API usually deviates.

Comment: phpinfo() contains only _SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"] :gzip,deflate

Comment: Can you try with the following,

In your .htaccess file:

"AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .zip"

add this above line.

Answer (score 2):

Provided that you actually have the ZIP extension available on the server, you could use [`dl()`](http://www.php.net/dl) to dynamically load it (<5.3).

```
if (!extension_loaded('zip')) {
    // Attempt to load the zip
    $prefix = (PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX === 'dll') ? 'php_' : '';
    dl($prefix . 'zip.' . PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX);

    if (!extension_loaded('zip')) {
        // Couldn't load the ZIP module dynamically, either
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

If you're using a version above 5.3.0, you won't be able to use `dl` unless it's running on the command line or embedded into a web server.

That leaves your only option to be modification of the `php.ini` if you can't recompile with the module built-in to PHP. You can't do this using `ini_set`, as that will only be applied at runtime whilst all of the required modules will already have been loaded by the PHP executable at startup.

Comment: This function has been removed from some SAPIs in PHP 5.3.

Comment: dl will be not enabled in some cases in php5.4, so it's better to recompile php with --enable-gzip

Comment: He explicitly stated that he didn't want to use `php.ini`. If he can't use that, do you really think he can recompile?

Comment: Well is the module actually on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Use this,

```
if (!extension_loaded('zip'))
{ 
    $prefix = (PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX == 'dll') ? 'php_' : '';
    dl($prefix . 'zip.' . PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX);
    if (!extension_loaded('zip')) 
    {
       return false;
    }
}
```